# HTML registration form to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="hw4.php" method="POST">
    Name: 
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    ID:
    <input type="text" name="ID">
    <br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="pass"> 
    <br>
    Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
    <br>
    Major:
    <input type="checkbox" name="major" value="Computer Science">Computer Science
    <input type="checkbox" name="major" value="Electronic Engineering">Electronic Engineering
    <input type="checkbox" name="major" value="Global Edison">Global Edison
    <input type="checkbox" name="major" value=ICT/>ICT
    <input type="checkbox" name="major" value="Economics">Economics
    <input type="checkbox" name="major" value="Management">Management
    <br>
    Year:
    <select name = "year">
        <option value="Freshman">Freshman</option>
        <option value="Sophomore">Sophomore</option>
        <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
        <option value="Senior">Senior</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    Message
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php

    $db_host = "localhost" ;
    $db_user = "root" ;
    $db_password = "ha9056";
    $db_name = "login" ;
    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name) ;

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
        echo "Database connection failed : ".mysqli_connect_error() ;
    else
        echo "Database connected<br><br>" ;

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $major=$_POST['major'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE NAME = '$name'" ;

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry) ;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;

    $qry = "INSERT INTO login VALUES('$name','$id','$pass','$gender','$major','$year','$message')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

 ?>
```

Hello everybody. I have a registration form here and want to add to mysql DB. I wrote down a php code but not working properly, anyone has recommendation for my code?? I would be really appreciated.
gender has to be shown as Male or Female in registration form and should be shown as M or F in mysql. and year must be shown as Freshman, sophomore, etc and should be saved as a number like 1,2,3,4 in mysql
Thank you so much.
Below is the image of mysql for now.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPqry.png)

Comment: You can change the value of your gender input to `M` and `F` instead, rather than `male` and `female`. Same as for the years

Comment: Oh it has to be shown as Male and Female in registration form and should be shown as F or M in mysql

Comment: What I mean is the value attribute of the input, it is still rendered as Male or Female, but the value you will get is either `M` or `F`, same for the years

Comment: Yep his right i doesn't matter in your input text will affect your value of input unless you want to change it with some script

Comment: Thank you man, in i edited my code as you revised however, value in mysql still shows as male and female and my MAJOR value is shown as Array and YEAR value is shown as 0. still some error on my code...

Comment: How come your year becomes 0 and the gender still the same? changing the value should also change the value you get

Comment: I just tried it and I'm getting either `M` or `F`, and `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`

Comment: some one should point out the huge security holes this code has

Answer (score -1):

Just change the values of the inputs

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">Male 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female
<select name = "year">
    <option value="1">Freshman</option>
    <option value="2">Sophomore</option>
    <option value="3">Junior</option>
    <option value="4">Senior</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain so that I can adjust accordingly